# How to create date parameter in multidimensional (mdx) query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a query in SQL server

```
select ID,
startdate,
Enddate
from dbo.order
where startdate between @startdate and @enddate
```

the problem is that we have just moved to SSAS multidimensional mode.
How can I write the above query in SSAS MDX

Comment: This depends on your stucture in the Cube: how does your date dimension look like? How is it connected to your facts? If you browse the cube in SSMS, you can create a query via drag and drop and then script this as MDX (from the toolbar) - this should give you a clue an how to proceed.

Comment: ANd what I just forgot: as far as I am informed, you don't have something like @parameter in MDX - usually you filter in the tool with which you read the cube, e.g. in Excel - there you can drag a dimension into the filter and add your selection there. If you need to access the data programatically, you can use SSIS and pass the parameters to the corresponding tasks, which then either handle the parameter on their own or which build the query string with the parameters and send them to the cube.